# C# having issue sorting accdb records via DataGridView (WF)

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access

I'm unable to sort the records descending per date,
Example:
I have 10000 records and I would like to see only 15 most recent records.

```
void fillgrid()
        {
            con.Open();
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select top 15 * from Records order by Date", con);
            DataTable dt= new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
            con.Close();

        }
```

Note: "Records" is name of table and "Date" is column which contains date and time.

I tried to sorting correctly within DB but it doesn't reflect my application Grid View.
With current code, it will sort from oldest to newest and I need other way around.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use `"select top 15 * from Records order by Date DESC"` . You can also sort the data-table by sorting the default-view of it or make a data-view of table and sort it.

Comment: Thank you Sir, I already tried with DESC but it seems I did something wrong :D

Comment: Can you provide some sample data to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0):

`Date` is a reserved word so try:

```
"select top 15 * from Records order by [Date] desc"
```